HttpClient Import prevents my componenent from working
I have an angular service connexionService in which I need some csv files I use HttpClient and a code that works in another component but when I add HttpClient to my constructor the webpage associated with my component doesnt show, it works fine without HttpClient, how do I get the infos of my csv files in a manner that works, sorry for the confusion : here's the code for ConnexionService :
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, User, authState, signOut, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConnexionService {

    constructor(private fbAuth: Auth, private http : HttpClient) { } 
    readonly obsUser: Observable<User | null> = authState(this.fbAuth) 
    //readonly userSignal= Signal<boolean>();
    //readonly userSignal = this.obsUser.pipe(Map(this.user => !!user))
    async logout(): Promise<void> { 
     return signOut(this.fbAuth); 
      
        } 
    async loginGoogle(): Promise<void> { 
      
          return signInWithPopup(this.fbAuth, new GoogleAuthProvider()).then( 
            (result) => {
              const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
             let token: string | undefined;
  
             if (credential) {
              token = credential.accessToken;
              } else { 
                 console.error("La credential est null.");
  }
              const user = result.user;
            }).catch((error) => {
              const errorCode = error.code;
              const errorMessage = error.message;
              const email = error.customData.email;
              const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
            }
      
        ) 
      
        } 
        lireLivreur(csvData:string){
          const lines=csvData.split('\n');
          const result:Livreur[]= [];
      
          const headers=lines[0].split(',');
          for(let i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
            const obj: ParsedData = {};
            const currentLine=lines[i].split(',');
            for(let j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
              obj[headers[j]]=currentLine[j];
            }
            const livreur:Livreur={
              trigramme:obj[headers[0]],
              prenom:obj[headers[1]],
              nom:obj[headers[2]],
              photo:obj[headers[3]],
              telephone:obj[headers[4]],
              emploi:obj[headers[5]],
              entrepot:obj[headers[6]],
              tournees:obj[headers[7]],
            }
            if(livreur.emploi=='livreur'){
              result.push(livreur);
            }     
          }
          return result;
        }
       
        
        lireInfos(){
          this.http.get('./assets/Export_Employés.csv',{responseType:'text'})
          .subscribe(data=>{
            this.livreurs=this.lireLivreur(data);
          },
        );
      }
      
        livreurs : Livreur[]=[];
         livreur: Livreur = {
          trigramme: '',
          prenom: '',
          nom: '',
          photo: '',
          telephone: '',
          emploi: '',
          entrepot: '',
          tournees: ''
        };   
     
    
      }


      interface Livreur {
        trigramme: string;
        prenom: string;
        nom: string;
        photo: string;
        telephone: string;
        emploi: string;
        entrepot: string;
        tournees: string;
      }    
      interface ParsedData {
        [key: string]: string;
      }
  
  




and the code for ConnexionComponent :
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ConnexionComponent {
    constructor(private cox: ConnexionService){
    }

    
 
    async logGoogle():Promise<void>{
        this.cox.loginGoogle();
    }
    async logOut():Promise<void>{
        this.cox.logout();
    }
  }

I didnt even start to inject my Connexion service into my compnent and it doesnt work so the problem must be with ConnexionService

Did you provide the HttpClientModule in your application ?
This can be done in one of two ways, if you are the standalone version of the Angular application boostraping you need to provide the HttpClient with the provideHttpClient function in your main.ts.
Angular Standalone :
main.ts
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient()
  ]
}) 

If your application is boostraped using a module, you'll need to import the HttpClientModule in your AppModule.
With Modules :
app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}


Thank you ! I didn't have a standrad angular project structure I had an app.config.ts file to which I added what you gave, I'm sorry to take so long to respond I'm forgetful these days
